# Provide explicit type specification despite `impl Trait` argument

Tags: generics, rust, numbers, closures, traits

Consider the following minimum example:

```
fn foo<T>(arg: T, f: impl FnOnce(i32) -> i32) -> Vec<T> {
   let mut x: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
   x.push(arg);
   println!("{:?}", f(5));
   x   
} 

fn main() {
   println!("{:?}", foo::<u32>(5, |i_arg| { i_arg + 5 }));
}
```

which does not compile because `impl Trait` is used:

```
error[E0632]: cannot provide explicit generic arguments when `impl Trait` is used in argument position
  --> src/main.rs:10:28
   |
10 |     println!("{:?}", foo::<u32>(5, |i_arg| { i_arg + 5 }));
   |                            ^^^ explicit generic argument not allowed

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `generic_functions`.
```

Is there any possibility for me to specify the type for `T` despite using `impl Trait` in the other argument? I am working in a codebase where I need to call a generic function which uses `impl Trait` but I need to specify the other generic types.

Answer (score 2):

From your example I don't understand why you're trying to use the turbofish. `T`'s type can be determined from the input argument `arg`. Whatever you pass in as `arg` will be what the compiler infers `T` to be. I updated your example to work:

```
fn foo<T>(arg: T, f: impl FnOnce(i32) -> i32) -> Vec<T> {
   let mut x: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
   x.push(arg);
   println!("{:?}", f(5));
   x   
} 

fn main() {
   println!("{:?}", foo(5u32, |i_arg| { i_arg + 5 }));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5fe06be63638e26543948d5c7308e3fb)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the problem is, I am in a setting where the type apparently cannot be determined from the input argument arg - that code is rather complicated, I will try to come up with an example that illustrates this problem.